# Обязательно ли делать вопрос "Книги и учебные ресурсы по ..." общим?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Обязательно ли делать вопрос `Книги и учебные ресурсы по ...` общим? Я хочу создать вопрос `Книги и учебные ресурсы по Godot и GDScript`, и думаю не сделать ли его не общим. Просто появляется такой соблазн получить много баллов репутации, к примеру:

- [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1) - 117 за или 1170 баллов репутации.
- [Книги и учебные ресурсы по JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-javascript) - 85 за или 850 баллов репутации.
- и т.д.

Но все они общие и автор ничего не получил.

Так вот, мой вопрос заключается в том, можно-ли делать такие вопросы не общими?

Comment: общим могут сделать модераторы ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Если я правильно помню была такая договорённость, что тему с книгами и литературой делать общими.....тем более как правило там всегда один ответ, который правят **все участники** сообщества. Поэтому он и общий........Оооооочень редко может ответов больше одного, но только потому, что в один ответ не вместилось

Comment: А если вами движет жажда наживы за репутацией нежели помощь людям - грош вам цена  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Не обольщайтесь большим количеством плюсов в тех темах. Их плюсуют так активно как раз потому, что они общие. Будь автор один - плюсов было бы на-а-амного меньше (да и минусов бы насовали полную панамку: мол, эта книга плохая, эта устаревшая, эту книгу забыл). Обратите внимание: на Мете плюсы тоже щедро раздают, потому как это не настоящая репутация.

Comment: Кроме того, стоит учитывать, что указанным вопросам уже более 7 лет. И за такой срок, рейтинг уже не кажется таким большим

Comment: А ещё надо учитывать то, что есть очень популярные языки, а есть не очень. А есть просто те, которые больше плюсуют... И вот если взять PHP или Unity3d - то там всего лишь по 20-25 плюсиков за всё время....... так что этот самый godot, который явно не в ТОПе - точно особо никто плюсовать не будет

Comment: Спасибо всем большое, сделаю вопрос общим.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Насколько я помню, вопрос делать общим не обязательно, а вот ответ - обязательно. Хотя, сейчас всего несколько из перечисленных вопросов авторские.

А ещё, вопрос общим может сделать только модератор, но не автор вопроса.

Comment: У меня как раз такой [вопрос по Fortran'у](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1408847), вопрос - авторский, ответ - общий. `А ещё, вопрос общим может сделать только модератор, но не автор вопроса.` - вообще, если вы только начинаете писать вопрос, то снизу есть галочка и так ВЫ сами можете сделать его общим, а вот после публикации уже только модератор.

Comment: @ΝNL993, так там галочка ответить, а не общим сделать.

Comment: И вправду, путаю.